# How can you add an attribute that has a space in between with js?

Tags: javascript, attributes

Ok, so here's part of a code. I got it from a website. I was given the code so I can embed it on another website. It's a live chat btw.

I need to inject the JS embed code through JS.
Here's part of the code. (I deleted some unnecessariy info)

```
<script id="abcd" data-cfasync="false" async src="//ab.abc.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 272px;height: 440px;">{"handle":"nitrotype","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"0084ef","b":100,"c":"FFFFFF","cvh":30}}</script>
```

I tried to do it using attributes.

```
var x = document.createElement("script");
    x.setAttribute("id", "abcd"
    x.setAttribute("data-cfasync = "false";
    x.setAttribute("async src
```

Well.. right there. `async src` it doesn't work. JS doesn't recognize that.
So I'm wondering if there is a work around this.

If you guys have any ideas, please let me know.
thx.

And, by the way, the `>` after 440px is part of it. That's the other thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may look like the attribute is called `async src` due to `async` not having an `=` after it, they are actually two separate values. As per [the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2), an attribute without a value defaults to the empty string. This is essentially for boolean attributes (either it's there or it's not), such as `async` and `defer` for script tags, or `disabled` for input tags. So, you'd just set two attributes:

```js
x.setAttribute("async", "");
x.setAttribute("src", "//ab.abc.com/js/gz/emb.js");
```

Comment: WOW! just wow – It's one of those things: "how did i not think of that".           well, thx for the answer.

Comment: One more question, which is not really related to what I originally asked. Do you see the ```>``` after the 440px? It's part of the code. How would I put that in the atttributes, or how would I make it be part of the code through JS? cuz I can't really do setAttribute with that ">"

Comment: The `>` is denoting the end of the attributes list. Everything after the `>` is inside the script tag.

Comment: hmm. It's not the the part where it closes the tag: NOT: ```<script x = "y".> </script>``` IT IS: this part of the code: ```style="width: 272px;height: 440px;">{...``` It is almost like it's wrapping things like an object like... >{a:x, b:y, x:{i:x, j:y}}

Comment: That is exactly where the opening script tag is terminated.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. The code being in one single line, made me think it was part of the attributes. Then after you told me what u just told me. I put a new line after >. And it all made sense. <script> {a:y, b{c:y}} </script>. GOT IT. THANKS AGAIN!